# ColorHttpMessageConverter but missing default constructor of Color

Tags: java, spring, spring-web, jackson-databind

To decode url-arguments to color I use this HttpMessageConverter:

```
public class ColorHttpMessageConverter implements HttpMessageConverter<Color> {

    @Override
    public boolean canRead(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return clazz == Color.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
        return clazz == Color.class;
    }

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getSupportedMediaTypes() {
        return Collections.singletonList(MediaType.ALL);
    }

    @Override
    public Color read(Class<? extends Color> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
        byte[] buff = new byte[6];
        if (inputMessage.getBody().read(buff) != buff.length) {
            throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Must read 6 bytes.");
        }
        String c = new String(buff);
        return Color.decode("#" + c);
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Color t, MediaType contentType, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
            throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
        outputMessage.getBody().write(Integer.toHexString(t.getRGB()).substring(2).getBytes());
    }

}
```

Then I write a rest-controller having this mapping:

```
@Transactional
@RequestMapping("a.jpg")
public ResponseEntity<BufferedImage> getA(Color textcolor) throws IOException {
```

I call the url `http://localhost:8080/myapp/rest/a.jpg?textcolor=ffffff` but i get only this  in console:

```
No primary or default constructor found for class java.awt.Color
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You should write a `Converter` and not an `HttpMessageConverter` and register it appropriatly.

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried HttpMessageConverter and beans.Converter. The second did not work because the `@ConstructorProperties` is strict http-request-parameter-name bound.

Comment: YOu need a `Converter<String, Color>` as mentioned. The `HttpMessageConverter` is for something else. Why would you need `@ConstructorProperties`?

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpMessageConverter` serves a whole different purpose, it is for translating the body into something else (or vice versa). What you want is a `Converter<String, Color>` and vice-versa, as you want to convert a request parameter and not the body to a `Color`.

```
public class StringToColorConverter implements Converter<String, Color> {

  public Color convert(String color) {
    return Color.decode("#" + color);
  }

}
```

and the other way

```
public class ColorToStringConverter implements Converter<Color,String> {

  public String convert(Color color) {
    return Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB()).substring(2);
  }

}
```

Now you can register them with a `WebMvcConfigurer`

```
@Configuration
public class MyWebConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    registry.addConverter(new StringToColorConverter()):
    registry.addConverter(new ColorToStringConverter()):
  }

}
```

Now the converter should be used when that method argument with type `Color` is detected.